# Writing a vector as linear sum of itself and its complex conjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vectors

Let $x$ be a complex number with a 2-norm of 1.

Let $\lambda$ be a vector (specifically, the eigenvector of an operator).

I'd like to rewrite $x\lambda$ as $y\lambda + y\overline\lambda$, where $y$ is a complex number with a 2-norm of 1.

Trying this myself, I found it easy to find a formula for y for a specific entry in $\lambda$ but I can't figure out how to do it for the entire vector.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be possible if the vector $\lambda$ is of a special form, namely $\lambda = av$ for $v$ a *real* vector, and $a$ a complex number. This is because $y \lambda + y \overline{\lambda} = y(\lambda + \overline{\lambda})$, and $\lambda + \overline{\lambda}$ consists of only real coordinates.